# Patterns in lookup table

Tags: c#

I have a switch block with patterns like this:

```cs
switch ( input ) {
  case { Property1: "abc" }:
    // do sth
    break;
  case { Property1: "def", Property2: 66 or 67 or 68 or 80 }:
    // do sth
    break;
}
```

I had the idea to have a list pattern, func which is ordered and I could iterate to apply the functions instead of writing the switch statement.

It seems the pattern is not storable in a variable, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the pattern is not storable in a variable, so I am stuck.

Yes, because they are effectively a syntactic sugar which is expanded by the compiler.

Personally I would go with `switch` statement/expression but an alternative can be list of tuples containing `Func`'s and actions. For example:

```
// if needed use Action<T, T1, ...> to provide parameters
var patterns = new List<(Func<MyClass, bool> pattern, Action action)>()
{
    (inp => inp is { Property1: "abc" }, () => { }),
    (inp => inp is { Property1: "def", Property2: 66 or 67 or 68 or 80 }, () => { }),
};

foreach (var pair in patterns)
{
    if (pair.pattern(input))
    {
        pair.action();
        // break; // if needed
    }
}
```